# How to add title attribute on HTML element with TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, attributes

I have this span:

```
<span class="first-span" (mouseover)="mouseover(params)" (mouseout)="out()">
  {{params.valueFormatted ? params.valueFormatted : params.value}}
</span>
```

What I want in TypeScript to add logic here on `mouseover` to add attribute title on the element, on `out` method to remove it. Any suggestion?

```js
async mouseover(params) {
  if (this.toolTip) { return; }
  this.handle = setTimeout(() => {
      this.checkSaldo(params.value, params.currencyCode ? params.currencyCode : params.currency).then((x) => {
          this.toolTip = x;
          this.show = true;
          // add toolTip value to attribute title and display
          return;
      });
  }, 1500);
}


out() {
  this.show = false;
  this.toolTip = null;
  //remove title attribute
  clearTimeout(this.handle);
}
```

Comment: Are you try to achieve the element such: `<span title="{{toolTip}">...</span>`?

Comment: yes but with condition...for example if toolTip value is undefined  then dont display title
tooltip ? title = {{toolTip}} : null... if you know what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the element with id: "first_span" via `@ViewChild`.
2. In `mouseover` method, check `toolTip` has value and the element (from *1*) is existed, then add the "title" attribute.
3. In `out` method, check the element (from *1*) has existed and the element has the "title" attribute, then remove the "title" attribute from the element.

```
<span #first_span class="first-span" (mouseover)="mouseover(params)" (mouseout)="out()">
  {{params.valueFormatted ? params.valueFormatted : params.value}}
</span>
```

```js
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('first_span') elem: ElementRef;

async mouseover(params) {
  this.handle = setTimeout(() => {
    this.checkSaldo(10, 'FRA').then((x) => {
      this.toolTip = x;
      this.show = true;

      if (this.toolTip && this.elem && this.elem.nativeElement)
        this.elem.nativeElement.setAttribute('title', this.toolTip);
    });
  }, 4000);
}

out() {
  this.show = false;
  this.toolTip = null;

  if (this.elem && this.elem.nativeElement) {
    let element = this.elem.nativeElement as HTMLElement;

    element.attributes.getNamedItem('title') &&
      element.attributes.removeNamedItem('title');
  }

  clearTimeout(this.handle);
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tj92zk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

With the use of Angular Material you could do this with MatTooltipModule : https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview